# XPATH - normalize-space with more than 1 text for counting purposes

Tags: php, html, curl, xpath, normalize-space

Hi everyone i'm noob at this,

https://decisoesesolucoes.com/agencias/albergaria/consultores

In the url above, i want to count the number of 'consultor imobiliario' and 'Consultora Imobiliaria' , both the text has spaces, so why im using the normalize-space .

[The text i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkTGk.png)

Example:

`"//*[text()[normalize-space() = 'consultor imobiliario']]"` - this works

But if i want to count also the 'Consultora Imobiliaria' doesn't work:

```
"//*[text()[normalize-space() = 'consultor imobiliario' and 'Consultora Imobiliária']]"
```

> (if I user OR instead AND the counting = bad count)

My intire code is :

```
$current_page = 1;
$max_page = 999999999999;
$countTotalConsultores=0;

while($max_page >= $current_page){

$url = "https://decisoesesolucoes.com/agencias/albergaria/consultores?page=";
$url .= $current_page;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$res = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DomDocument();
@ $dom->loadHTML($res);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$body = $xpath->query("//*[text()[normalize-space() = 'consultor imobiliario' and 'Consultora Imobiliária']]"); 
$count = $body->length;

$countTotalConsultores = $countTotalConsultores+$count;

echo "        Página atual:" .$current_page . "No. of agents " . $countTotalConsultores;

$current_page = $current_page+1;

if ($count < 1){
    break;
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: If you only want to count the occurence, why not use `substr_count()` on `$res`?

Comment: @Michel , PHP Warning:  substr_count() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /volume1/www/iad/tools/curling_decisoes_solucoes_consultores.php on line 28

Comment: Can you help me with the code?

Comment: @Michel in practice that should work fine. in theory it's subject to issues like "[parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003)", eg it would incorrectly count ```<!-- consultor imobiliario -->``` instances (in practice there won't be any such instances, it's a purely theoretical issue :P )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you're looking for

```
"//*[text()[contains(normalize-space(), 'consultor imobiliario') or contains(normalize-space(),'Consultora Imobil')]]"
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**

You are trying to find text-nodes that are both equal to have 2 different values. That wil never match anything. It is like saying give me all days in summer that are both 100% sunny and 100% rainy.

Use `or` in stead of `and` like this:

```
"//*[text()[normalize-space() = 'consultor imobiliario' or normalize-space() ='Consultora Imobiliária']]"
```

Comment: that will return everything because the string literal `Consultora Imobiliária` is true-ish,  you probably meant to write ```"//*[text()[normalize-space() = 'consultor imobiliario' or normalize-space() = 'Consultora Imobiliária']]"``` - notably you inherited that bug from copy-pasting OP's bugged xpath, though ^^ OP also has the same bug

Comment: Thanks for the help Siege Jongebloed , however de code it counts only the 'consultor imobiliario' .

The 'Consultora Imobiliária' text is not counting.

Will it be because of having accents?

Comment: If i put this "//*[text()[normalize-space() = 'consultor imobiliario' or 'Consultora Imobiliária']]"    the count will count millions ...

And the result should be like 7 ...

Comment: @hanshenrik: you are correct. I have updated the answer

Comment: @Zuclaspt yeah that was caused by the bug i mentioned above. the xpath has been updated, try the updated version ^^

Comment: @hanshenrik, i've put $tables = $xpath->query("//*[text()[normalize-space() = 'consultor imobiliario' or normalize-space() ='Consultora Imobiliária']]");  

And only count's 3 agents instead counting 5 agents ...

Only the node 'consultor imobiliario' its counting :(

I've to found a solution

Comment: @Zuclaspt sigh, that's because it looks for a node containing those 2 exact strings *and nothing else*, one of the tags you're looking for has the text ` Consultora Imobiliária e Financeira`, which is not *just*`Consultora Imobiliária`, seems you need contains()

Comment: @hanshenrik, with this code, how I want to add various url's for the count,, how i can add multiple url's ? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Zuclaspt sounds like a job for array() + foreach(...) + [xpath_quote()](https://gist.github.com/divinity76/64b0c12bcafc2150efa8ca87d2ccee52) + string concatenation, eg ```$xp=""//*[text()[";foreach($needles as $needle){$xp.="normalize-space() = ".xpath_quote($needle)." OR"; }``` ~~

Comment: @hanshenrik , sorry im noob at this...

How that code can seek for multiple url's? 

In my code I had: 

$url = "https://decisoesesolucoes.com/agencias/albergaria/consultores?page=";

However I want to seek also in "https://decisoesesolucoes.com/agencias/ABRANTES/consultores?page=";

Comment: @Zuclaspt that's irrelevant for this thread, if you're stuck on that, perhaps make a new thread about that problem.

Comment: i've just opened another thread.. Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68807538/xpath-multiple-urls